# TerminateProcess() Fails when called upon a 32 bin application in a 64 bin machine

Tags: c++, windows-7-x64

Please go through below code:

```
LPSTR commandBuffer = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\"";
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE;
if (CreateProcess(NULL,
    commandBuffer,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &si,
    &pi)) {

    Sleep(5000);
    UINT exitCode = 0;
    if (!TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, exitCode))
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Here when I create a process with 32 bin application (Notepad++.exe) on a 64 bin Windows 7 machine `TerminateProcess()` fails with error code 5 (Access denied) but if I create a process with a 64 bit application (i.e. `LPSTR commandBuffer = "\"C:\\Program Files\\depends22_x64\\depends.exe\""`) on the same machine there is no error. I need to understand why this is happening and how can I be able to properly terminate a process created with 32 bit application on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
if (TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, exitCode))
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
```

TerminateProcess returns 0 on failure and a code other than 0 on success. The C++ if() statement evaluates non-zero values as true and zero as false. So, you need to write:

```
if (TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, exitCode) == 0)
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
```

---

As for the actual problem. I cannot reproduce it on Windows 10 64 bit, but if it persists, try the following:

Instead of using the process handle returned from `CreateProcess()`, create a new handle using `OpenHandle()` explicitly specifying `PROCESS_TERMINATE` on the process id returned from `CreateProcess()`. Then use that handle to terminate the process using `ProcessTerminate()`.

---

What you also need to consider is that applications like notepad++ will automatically terminate itself when they are already running and instead activate the already running process, maybe telling the already running instance to open a file or some such. In this case, terminating the created process has no effect on the process that was already running before.

Comment: The handle from CreateProcess will always have full access.  I would hazard a guess that `depends.exe` might be self-elevating, or crashing, or otherwise behaving unexpectedly.

Comment: @NineBerry: Corrected the mistake in the program as pointed by you, thanks. I will try your suggestion of creating a new handle and use that to terminate the process. Thanks for the response.

Comment: OpenHandle() worked perfectly!